# Select a computed column made of concatenation of 2 existing column on table sql server m

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say i have a 'People' table which has 2 columns

- first_name
- last_name

I wish to

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' , ', last_name) AS full_name
FROM People;
```

Which I'll expect to produce:
Column name full_name, and value such as 'John , Doe'.

I read about `CONCAT` built-in function on version 2012 and on. What are my options when my version is older?

Comment: Just do `Select first_name + ', ' + last_name as full_name`

Comment: columns are nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`+` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT first_name + ' , ' + last_name full_name
       FROM people;
```

Comment: be carefull if a column is nullable

Comment: To expand a bit: CONCAT does a few things that the + operator doesn't do: It will automagically replace NULL with an empty string (the the whole shebang doesn't become NULL) and it also converts other types (like int) to a string.